# Are callbacks needed to ensure transaction-like behavior on insert?

Tags: meteor

Let's say I have a method which looks like:

```
commentsInsert: (comment) ->
  Comments.insert comment, (err) ->
    throw err if err
    updateCommentCounts()
```

The goal here is to avoid calling `updateCommentCounts` if the insert failed. If this code runs only on the server could I skip the callback and the `throw`? For example:

```
commentsInsert: (comment) ->
  Comments.insert comment
  updateCommentCounts()
```

The meteor docs say:

> On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then insert blocks until the database acknowledges the write, or throws an exception if something went wrong.

I'm assuming this means it will bail out of the function and return an error code to the caller. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to test this I added a unique index to the comments collection and did two identical inserts. The second insert threw an error (as expected), sent a `500` to the client, and bailed out of the method. So it seems as if the answer to my question is: yes, I can skip the callback.